# How to draw italic text with PIL/ImageDraw?

Tags: python, windows, python-imaging-library, italic

I want to draw italic text with PIL/ImageDraw.
Someone says use italic fonts, but my font is just only one ttf file. No italic font file.

```
fontName = 'malgun.ttf'      # One of Korean fonts.
fontSize = 25
imgMode = 'RGBA'
fillColor = (0, 0, 0)
bgColor = (255, 255, 255)
font = ImageFont.truetype(os.path.join(os.environ['WINDIR'], 'fonts', fontName), fontSize)
img = Image.new(imgMode, font.getsize(c), bgColor)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((0, 0), c, fill=fillColor, font=font)
```

According to PIL documents, there are some additional options using libraqm, but that not support MS Windows.

Anyone help me?